# Atom - Python - Autocomplete

Tags: python, python-3.x, autocomplete, atom-editor

I am new to Programming and Python as well as Atom Editor. 
Currently, I try to install the autocomplete package in Atom Editor.

As you can see, I also checked the $PATH variable. 
[image: Picture (1)]

Unfortunately, it is not working.
[image: Picture (2)]

What I would like to have: [image: GIF (1)]

Please can someone help me.
Regards

Comment: Have you tried install `autocomplete-python` package, as suggested in one of the answer?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, when I used Atom, it comes with it's own package manager. So if you want to install this package(https://atom.io/packages/autocomplete-python) for example, all you need to do is run:

```
apm install autocomplete-python
```

autocomplete-python because that's the package name highlighted in green in the website.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Atom menu and under that menu select preferences. It opens a window where you can search for and install extensions. You'll see a column of icons and the bottom one reads Install. When you click on that you will get a search box and enter name of package you are looking for. When it appears just select install.

Answer (score -3):

I recommend more visual code and install the python library and autocomplet everything
VISUAL CODE is the best